# Azure ACS - How to create ingress controller with internal load balancer

Tags: azure, acs, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

I want to create ingress controller in my ACS cluster to access services.

Using helm I can achieve this (with below command), but the ingress controller is exposed to internet through External Load Balancer.

```
helm install stable/nginx-ingress
```

All services in the cluster are internal and dont need to be exposed to  internet. They will be accessed from applications running in same vnet.

How do I create a ingress controller that is not public but instead can be accessed through a Internal Load Balancer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

helm fetch stable/nginx-ingress to download the ingress helm chart.
Unzip and go to the templates Directory.  Edit the controller-service.yaml remove the condition and add the line service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
it should now look like;

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
labels:
```

apply the local helm chart and you will get a ingress controller with a internal IP address.  perform a kubectl get svc -n xxxxx (namespace you install the nginx-ingress controller into).  It should eventually look something like this.

factual-bat-nginx-ingress-controller  LoadBalancer  10.0.65.21 10.136.0.7